# Java PDF viewer with FDF

Tags: java, pdf

My company needs a PDF viewer with Java API with the additional requirement on being able to use FDF form data.

The only one i found was [JPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/index.php) which promises to feature everything we need, but it costs a bunch. So what are my options? Is there another tool to do it?

edit:

I found [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) to be an easy way to merge FDF data into the PDF form.

The only LGPL viewer that worked *ok* (unlike Adobe's own 10 year old Java 1.1 API) was Sun's [pdf-renderer](https://pdf-renderer.dev.java.net/). But sadly it doesn't display form values. iText's form-flattening helps, but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Foxit SDK. http://www.foxitsoftware.com/ The cost seems at bit less and i'm sure you'll get much more.

Maybe Open Office has something in its belt for you?

I also just found those:

http://www.crionics.com/

http://www.qoppa.com/

http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for mentioning these.
But Foxit doesn't have a Java API. And the Multivalent site... well, i kinda decided not to go further.

crionics and qoppa sound very good. I'll give them a try.

Comment: Which PDF viewer have you used finally?

Comment: Actually - Adobe Reader. So we are creating PDF files with iText and then show them in Adobe. We would have liked to have more control over the viewer and events, but all the Java implementations had problems (mostly with forms). For internal tooling we are using pdf-renderer, which only fails with half of the PDF document variants and is free.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Big Faceless' Java Viewer: http://big.faceless.org/products/pdfviewer/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/ (probably you will have to dig a little in it if you would like to find what you are searching for, but I think you'll find)

Comment: I don't think that's what i'm looking for. I need a viewer. And as far as i understood pdftk only uses iText to create and transform PDF files - no viewer.

Answer (score 0):

A year ago I was searching for something similar but I was unable to find anything useful, so ended up calling acrobat reader (which is only a workaround of course). Thanks for mentioning pdf-renderer (the project was not existing a year ago, at least I was unable to find it) in your question.

Comment: The way it looks that's what we are going to do, too. pdf-renderer is nice, but we need editable forms and our clients already bought acrobat writer for everyone, so... *sigh*